# What is an Isolated Word™?

Tags: word, pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an Isolated Word™.

Use the following examples to find the rule:

```
Isolated Words™,Not Isolated Words™

Reclusive,Affable
Abandoned,Cordial
Empty,Convivial
Aloof,Upbeat
Singular,Receptive
```

Comment: You [reposted](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42931/what-is-an-isolated-word)?

Comment: Is it significant that some of the words are spelled incorrectly ("Abandonded", "Convival"), or is this just an error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the limited examples that we have,

> An isolated word is a word which has a similar meaning to, well, isolated

Nothing much to write,

> Reclusive, Abandoned, Empty,Aloof,Singular all have almost the same meaning of isolated.. synonyms to a certain extent.

The non-isolated words

> Are somewhat antonyms of isolated..

Comment: Why is this not accepted yet